# How can I return an array of results from one worksheet based on criteria from another worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope the title of this makes sense. I've been trying to figure the best way to work what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a worksheet with a validation list of dates. I am trying to return all of the rows from a table, based on the date, but the date is in a second table.

Here is a mockup of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

| Install Schedule |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Site Number | Site Name | Install Date |
| 1 | Fuddruckers | 3/6/2024 |
| 8002 | Burger King | 3/7/2024 |  |
| 8003 | Taco Bell | 2/5/2024 |  |
| 8006 | Taco Bell | 2/20/2024 |  |
| 8007 | Taco Bell | 2/20/2024 |  |
| 8010 | Taco Bell | 2/21/2024 |  |
| 8011 | Burger King | 3/7/2024 |  |
| 12 | IHOP | 3/7/2024 |  |
| 8014 | Burger King | 2/20/2024 |  |

| Computer List |  |
| --- | --- |
| Site Number | Computer Name |
| 1 |  |
| 1 | TABLE01_1 |
| 1 | TABLE01_2 |
| 8002 | QUICK02_2 |
| 8002 | QUICK02_1 |
| 8002 | QUICK02_3 |
| 8006 | QUICK06_6 |
| 8006 | QUICK06_5 |
| 8007 | QUICK07_6 |
| 8007 | QUICK07_4 |
| 8010 | QUICK10_4 |
| 8010 | QUICK10_5 |
| 8011 | QUICK11_5 |
| 8011 | QUICK11_7 |
| 8011 | QUICK11_6 |
| 12 | TABLE12_2 |
| 12 | TABLE12_1 |
| 12 | TABLE12_3 |
| 8014 | QUICK14_7 |
| 8014 | QUICK14_6 |
| 8014 | QUICK14_5 |
| 8014 | QUICK14_9 |

| Results |  |
| --- | --- |
| Site Number | Computer Name |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |

Cell F2 is a validation list of dates.

The table **Install Schedule** has all of the site numbers, with the dates that devices are being installed.

Table **Computer List** is a list of computers by site number.

I would like to return a list of computers by the date they are being installed. I figure that I need to use a LET statement, but I've been having trouble figuring out the correct formulas. Using the following formula, I can get a list of the sites by date:

```
=FILTER(Schedule[Site Number],Schedule[Install Date]=SelectedDate)
```

That returns a list of sites by date. But I'm not sure how to use that to return the list of computers by site.

Thanks

Comment: If you provide your sample data as text, best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) within the question it is easier to help you.

Comment: An index() with match() - lots of examples of the use on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E6</kbd>

```
=FILTER(Computers,1-ISNA(XMATCH(Computers[Site Number],
 FILTER(Schedule[Site Number],F2=Schedule[Install Date]))))
```

---

Where:

- `Computers` --> Table Starts from `I16:J38`
- `Schedule` --> Table Starts from `I3:K12`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! I didn't think of using XMATCH. I haven't used it much, so  don't know how it works too well.

Comment: @Harlan pleased to know it worked for you =)